# symbolizing and replacing a value in hash values in hash of array of hash

Tags: ruby, hash-of-hashes

I have a data structure which is something similar to this

```
  lib_data = {'library'=>[{"type"=>"Books", 
  "checkout"=>false, "data"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "operator"=>"AND", "details"=>{"property"=>"Name", "author"=>"%s", 
  "name"=>"%s"}}, {"type"=>"Books", "criteria"=>{"property"=>"Revision", "operator"=>"%s", 
  "value"=>"%s"}}]}]}
```

I am trying to symobolize all the keys first and then insert values in keys represented by inplace of %s

I was able to monkey patch a small bit of code into Hash class that would gets me to symbolize all the hash values using something like this

```
def symbolize_all_keys
    keys.each do |k|
      key = k.to_sym
      value = delete(k)
      store(key, value)
    end
    self
  end
```

and then just use `lib_data.symbolize_all_keys` but this symbolizes one key

Is there a more idomatic way to symbolize all keys ?

also wanted a way insert values into the keys that have %s values?

Comment: Rails has [`Hash#deep_symbolize_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) or there are gems like the [`deep_hash_transformer`](https://github.com/spickermann/deep_hash_transformer#complex-example) that do exactly what you need: Transforming recursively keys in hashes. Even if you do not use Rails and do not want on include further gems, you might want to have at their source code how these gems work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Hash#transform_keys!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21) in a recursive way, something like:

```
def symbolize_all_keys(h)
  if h.is_a? Hash
    h.transform_keys!(&:to_sym)
    h.values.each do |val|
      val.each { |v| symbolize_all_keys(v) } if val.is_a? Array
      symbolize_all_keys(val)
    end
  end
  h
end

symbolize_all_keys(lib_data)

lib_data
#=> {:library=>[{:type=>"Books", :checkout=>false, :data=>[{:type=>"Books", :operator=>"AND", :details=>{:property=>"Name", :author=>"%s", :name=>"%s"}}, {:type=>"Books", :criteria=>{:property=>"Revision", :operator=>"%s", :value=>"%s"}}]}]}
```

---

For the second part, not clear which value is replacing "%s" depending on the key.

Just an idea, similar to the recursive one above:

```
def replace_val(h, new_val = 'new_val')
  if h.is_a? Hash
    h.each do |key, val|
      h[key] = new_val if val == '%s'
      val.each { |v| replace_val(v) } if val.is_a? Array
      replace_val(val)
    end
  end
  h
end

replace_val(lib_data)

lib_data
#=> {:library=>[{:type=>"Books", :checkout=>false, :data=>[{:type=>"Books", :operator=>"AND", :details=>{:property=>"Name", :author=>"new_val", :name=>"new_val"}}, {:type=>"Books", :criteria=>{:property=>"Revision", :operator=>"new_val", :value=>"new_val"}}]}]}
```

Here you have access to the key of the value, but not to higher levels.

Comment: this worked for me without much issues. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails, you can use [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)

You can also access this class outside of Rails, require the core extension with:

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access"

2.6.5 :015 > lib_data = {'library'=>[{"type"=>"Books",
2.6.5 :016 >           "checkout"=>false, "data"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "operator"=>"AND", "details"=>{"property"=>"Name", "author"=>"%s",
2.6.5 :017 >                 "name"=>"%s"}}, {"type"=>"Books", "criteria"=>{"property"=>"Revision", "operator"=>"%s",
2.6.5 :018 >                 "value"=>"%s"}}]}]}
 => {"library"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "checkout"=>false, "data"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "operator"=>"AND", "details"=>{"property"=>"Name", "author"=>"%s", "name"=>"%s"}}, {"type"=>"Books", "criteria"=>{"property"=>"Revision", "operator"=>"%s", "value"=>"%s"}}]}]}
2.6.5 :019 > lib_data[:library]
 => nil
2.6.5 :020 > lib_data = lib_data.with_indifferent_access
 => {"library"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "checkout"=>false, "data"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "operator"=>"AND", "details"=>{"property"=>"Name", "author"=>"%s", "name"=>"%s"}}, {"type"=>"Books", "criteria"=>{"property"=>"Revision", "operator"=>"%s", "value"=>"%s"}}]}]}
2.6.5 :021 > lib_data[:library]
 => [{"type"=>"Books", "checkout"=>false, "data"=>[{"type"=>"Books", "operator"=>"AND", "details"=>{"property"=>"Name", "author"=>"%s", "name"=>"%s"}}, {"type"=>"Books", "criteria"=>{"property"=>"Revision", "operator"=>"%s", "value"=>"%s"}}]}]
```